# Iterate over multiple elements of the same type for JQuery datepicker

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, datepicker

I'm trying to use a simple datepicker in an MVC application and need to call the datepicker whenever one of the input fields has an `id` ending in `Date`.

The field names are picked up from the view models and I'd prefer to have as little additional information attached as possible (e.g. I could add a different class to each input and script a datepicker for each one but that seems like overkill).

I can create an array of elements and can call each one by it's index.

```
var dateSelect = [];
$("[id$='Date']").each(function() {
    dateSelect.push('#' + $(this).attr('id'));
    console.log(dateSelect);
});

$(dateSelect[0]).datepicker({ format: "dd/mm/yyyy" });
```

How can I change this to call the datepicker for every instance of a Date field without knowing how many there are in the array?

e.g. `$(dateSelect[ANY]).datepicker({ format: "dd/mm/yyyy" });`

I've tried using `each` and a `for loop` but the datepicker only seems to appear if it's called directly after the field element.

### Edit for clarity

Judging by the first few comments I may not have been clear on why I need to answer this question.

When I call the datepicker on a page with multiple date fields, any actions called on the datepicker (e.g. onChange) are only applied to the first instance no matter which field is actually in focus.

I thought using an array of field elements would make it simple to call each one individually. I need to know how to make the call to an unknown number of elements in the array, as per the example:

```
$(dateSelect[ANY]).datepicker({ format: "dd/mm/yyyy" });
```

The question is not how to attach a datepicker to multiple fields.

### Update on Answer

The following code works. The original problem I was having was caused by the datepicker having two different samples showing different methods for hiding. For some reason the one I was trying to use only attached to the first instance of a date field on the page.

```
$("[id$='DateInput']").datepicker({ format: "dd MM yyyy" }).focus(function() {
    $(this).on('changeDate', function () {
        $(this).datepicker('hide');
        })
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to iterate.. If you call `.datepicker()` on a collection, it will be applied to all the elements in the collection:

http://jsfiddle.net/z88KG/

```
$("[id$='Date']").datepicker();
```

Comment: This is what I was doing but if there are more than one date fields on a page, additional logic (e.g. onChange) is only applied to the first instance. I need to be able to call each one individually.

Comment: Can you show the onChange function? My guess is that you just need to use `this` to reference the target of the event.

Comment: It looks like the datepicker I'm using has two methods for hiding the datepicker when a date is selected. I've switched the code around and it works okay. I'll update the question with the working code and mark this as the answer as the `jsfiddle` alerted me to the possible error.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just create the `datepicker` instance within each iteration of `each`?

```
$("[id$='Date']").each(function() {
    $(this).datepicker({ format: "dd/mm/yyyy" });
});
```

Comment: This still doesn't address the question of how I call each instance without knowing how many there are.

Answer (score 0):

If you add a class to all those inputs such as `.datepicker` you won't need to script a datepicker for each one just include one reference to the class you use.

`$(function(){  $(".datepicker").datepicker(); });`

[Example Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/l1ght/ectPn/)

Comment: This is not really any different to using the end of string wildcard on the field name. It doesn't alter the fact that I can't call each instance of the datepicker individually.